How do I identify this WW1 shell casing?


Can someone help me with any info on a shell casing that my great grandfather brought home from the war? It’s 7 1/4” tall and 3 1/4” wide.

You should give the dimensions of the casing.

Ok I apologize I wasn’t thinking, that would help lol, I’ll get that and send it thanks so much

Incomplete, but some information, as requested.

"St" ("stark"): a strengthened shell case.
"HL" is for "Haniel Luege", a Düsseldorf-based brass factory (Germany).
"1915" is for the year.
"NOVB": November probably.

Digging deeply, I found that on many (German and others) types of ammunition like this one, there's also the ID of the inspector. What puzzles me here is than HL is for the arsenal/factory, but HL coincidentally and probably stands also for the inspector.
So, my educated guess would be HL 57 for the manufacturer and batch, and HL 8 for the inspector name and ID. Or conversly, as there's no way to be sure which one is usually stamped on top/bottom.
There are tens of websites helping identify ammunition, I used The Western Front Museum.
